# Is this a plausible interpretation of the movie "The Next Three Days"?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, the-next-three-days

There is a scene in ***The Next Three Days*** where Russel Crowe’s character is explaining don Quixote to his students. He says something on the lines of “we can make our reality what we want it to be..”. After this point the movie takes a turn to the larger than life story. He plans an elaborate escape which is successful.

Was the planning and the actual escape all a part of his imagination in an attempt to cope up with the fact that his wife was gonna be in jail for life? The escape seems to good to be true and gave a dreamy vibe. I could not find any such interpretation online, though.